# Why is the first Integer 2147483648?

Tags: integer, ada

I'm trying to learn Ada, and this surprised me.

The output of this program:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is

function lstrip(S: String) return String is
begin
    return S(S'First+1 .. S'Last);
end;

function "&"(Left: String; Right: Integer) return String is
begin
    return Left & lstrip(Integer'Image(Right));
end "&";

function "&"(Left: Integer; Right: String) return String is
begin
    return lstrip(Integer'Image(Left)) & Right;
end "&";

begin
   Put_Line("Integer'First=" & Integer'First);
   Put_Line("Integer'Last=" & Integer'Last);
end Main;
```

Is this:

```
Integer'First=2147483648
Integer'Last=2147483647
```

But why is `Integer'First` larger than `Integer'Last`? I would expect it to be a negative number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Why is the first Integer 2147483648?**

It isn't.

Your `lstrip` function removes the first character of its argument.

`Integer'Image(Integer'First)` returns `"-2147483648"`. Your `lstrip` function changes that to `"2147483648"`.

It looks like you're trying to remove the leading space added by `Integer'Image` (I've always found that annoying myself). But `Integer'Image` adds that leading space only for non-negative numbers. Try this version of `lstrip`:

```
function lstrip(S: String) return String is
begin
    if S(S'First) = ' ' then
        return S(S'First+1 .. S'Last);
    else
        return S;
    end if;
end;
```

Note that `-2147483648` is a very common value for `Integer'First`, but the standard only guarantees that it's no greater than `-32767`.

Comment: That is peculiar. Thank you!

Comment: To be precise, `Integer'Image (Integer'First)` returns the image of `Integer'First`, the smallest value Integer can hold. This is no larger than –(2**15)+1 [ARM 3.5.4(21)] but may be smaller. Relying on it being -2147483648 is not portable.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter: Quite correct, I should have mentioned that (and now I have).